# The oddities with processing integers in a list as string

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Can anyone explain this to me pls? I was actually working on a generating [palindromic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number) and found that this doesn't work:

```
>>> [ str(x) for x in xrange(10,20) if x == x[::-1] ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

A little after, running this:

```
>>> [ str(x) for x in xrange(10,20) ]
['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19']
```

which is actually creating the list with the numbers as string (did I get this wrong??), whilst, this returns an empty set:

```
>>> [ str(x) for x in xrange(10,20) if x == '12' ]
[]
```

but this doesn't:

```
>>> [ str(x) for x in xrange(10,20) if x == 12 ]
['12']
```

My understanding is the elements in the generate list are *string*, `type()` confirms that too:

```
>>> type([ str(x) for x in xrange(10,20)][2])
<type 'str'>
```

then why `x == x[::-1]` doesn't work? What am I missing here? Any pointer is highly appreciated. Cheers!!

Comment: You seem to be missing some basics. `str(x)` returns a string representation of `x`, which is an int. So, you're comparing an int to a string.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary: that's what  palindromic numbers are, try with: `[ x for x in xrange(10,50) if str(x) == str(x)[::-1] ]` you will see. Cheers!!

Comment: @Keyser: I'm sure I was missing some basics and I knew that "str(x) is a string representation of x" but thing I was under wrong impression that I was thinking the comparison is happing on string representation of x. Edgar's reply explains that clearly. Cheers!!

Comment: Anyone care giving the reason for down-voting? I'm pretty sure, the person down-voted faced similar sort of problems and learned from that. It's good to remember the the old-days sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The str(x) happens after the filtering, but the filter you applied is on x, which is an integer.

Comment: thanks Edgar, that's explains my "mis-understanding" clearly. Cheets!!

Comment: @MacUsers np, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

`x` is int object:

```
>>> [str(x) for x in xrange(10,20) if isinstance(x, int)]
['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19']
>>> [str(x) for x in xrange(10,20) if isinstance(x, str)]
[]
```

---

```
>>> [str(x) for x in xrange(10,20) if str(x) == str(x)[::-1]]
['11']
```